# SQL Pivot filter out all NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, ssms

I'm trying to make a pivot for employer absences but I need to filter out the `NULL` values in SQL.

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @columns = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(Datum) 
                         FROM
                             (SELECT DISTINCT Datum
                              FROM table1
                              WHERE Datum > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
                                AND Datum < DATEADD(day, +13, GETDATE())) sub
                
                         ORDER BY Datum
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Vorname, Nachname, Bezeichnung, datum 
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.Mitarbeiter_ID = b.Mitarbeiter_ID) t 
PIVOT
    (MAX(Bezeichnung)
     FOR datum IN ('+ @columns +')
    ) AS pivot_table;';


EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

And this is the result of running the query:

[SQL Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCMiW.png)

How do I get the NULL values filtered out?

This is how the source data looks like, and there are blank columns:

| First Name | Last Name | Bezeichnung | Datum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First Name | Last Name | Urlaub | 2022-08-03 00:00:00.000 |
| First Name | Last Name | Urlaub | 2022-08-03 00:00:00.000 |
| First Name | Last Name | Urlaub | 2022-08-03 00:00:00.000 |
| First Name | Last Name |  | 2022-08-03 00:00:00.000 |
| First Name | Last Name |  | 2022-08-03 00:00:00.000 |
| First Name | Last Name |  | 2022-08-03 00:00:00.000 |

As soon as I query this into a pivot, the blank columns are returned as NULL.

I need the source data not to show the NULL/Empty values between the date range.

Comment: The `null` values indicate that there are no corresponding values in the source data. What would you have the query output instead of `null`?

Comment: Change `left join` to `join` maybe? Please do not post images of code or data, please paste them in as text

Comment: changing 'left join' to 'join' doesnt change anything

Comment: Please reach this [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) then include a minimal example dataset that demonstrates your issue. *(One we can test and develop with, and use to demonstrate that any answer satisfies your requirements.)*

Comment: Your screenshot shows no completely `NULL` columns. There are some which are `''` so perhaps just put `WHERE Bezeichnung <> ''` in the `SELECT @columns` query

Comment: tried with WHERE Bezeichnung <> '' but it still shows up

Comment: i did it with WHERE Bezeichnung <> '''' in the subquery. thanks anyway